# displaying value and label on dropdown using angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Im using angular to bind a dropdown to preview the `value` and `label` at the end of a page:

```
<select name="studyType" ng-model="studyType" class="form-control">
    <option value="1"> Clinical Trials </option>
    <option value="2"> Compassionate </option>
    <option value="3"> Other </option>
</select>
```

at the preview section im using:

```
Study Type: {{studyType}}
```

to display the selected `option`. 
For example: when Clinical Trials is selected, the output is:

```
Study Type: 1
```

Is there any way to make the value and the label printed together like:

```
Study Type: 1 - Clinical Trials
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below method 
**Controller**

```
  $scope.lists = [
    {name: 'Clinical Trials', value : 1},
    {name: 'Compassionate', value : 2},
    {name: 'Other', value : 3}
  ]
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="studyType" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in lists">
</select>
```

**Preview Section**

```
Study Type: {{studyType.value}} - {{studyType.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<select ng-model="studyType" ng-options="item for (name, value) in lists">    
  </select>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/E9bU5/157/

**NOTE :** Small issue in the above fiddle, dropdown values are not showing up. You can try something like that.

**Ref:**  http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/select/

Answer (score 0):

without recreating option list in $scope variable, we can achieved this by creating "id" of combobox.

let's try this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
   var app = angular.module('selectCbxApp', []);
   app.controller('cbxCntrl', function() 
  {
     var self = this;
     self.selectedStudyType = "";
        self.studyTypeChange = function()
        {         
        var studyCbxObj = document.getElementById("studyCbxId");
        self.selectedStudyType = studyCbxObj.options[studyCbxObj.selectedIndex].value + "-" + studyCbxObj.options[studyCbxObj.selectedIndex].text;
        }     
 });   
</script>

<body ng-app="selectCbxApp">  
   <div ng-controller="cbxCntrl as cbxCntrlAs">       
    Study Type:{{cbxCntrlAs.selectedStudyType}}</br>
       <select id="studyCbxId" class="form-control" ng-model="studyType" ng-change="cbxCntrlAs.studyTypeChange()">
      <option  value="1" > Clinical Trials </option>
      <option  value="2" > Compassionate </option>
      <option  value="3" > Other </option>
    </select>
   </div>    
</body>
</html>
```